# Merging two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables:

t1:

```
SSN            NAME       LAST       AD           SAL
-------------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----------
s1             paps                              2600
s2             raj                               1500
s3             rahul
```

t2:

```
SSN        NAME       LAST       AD           SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----------
s1                    mukh       sbc
s2                    sar        mdn
s3                    das        tly          1100
```

I want to merge these two table into one like

t3:

```
ssn  name  last   ad   sal
---- ----- ----- ---- ----
s1   paps  mukh  sbc  2600
s2   raj   sar   mdn  1500
s3   rahul das   tly  1100
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please elaborate if you want to INSERT or CREATE/SELECT

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with the database software being used, e.g. MySQL or SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @terence: anythings which gives the resultset.

Comment: @jack maney: suppose firstly dere was only one table... values from the columns have been distributed into two tables which are t1 and t2 and now I want to merge the two tables to get the result set as parent table.

Comment: @SayantanMukherjee - I didn't ask you about what you want. I asked you about [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Is `name` always null in t2?  What if it's different than in `t1`?

Answer (score 2):

well you have 4 different ways to merge a table.

- First of all, you can create a query, which gives you the result as if it was a merge:

a simple join:

tsql

- or you may want to create a view, which is a new table which values are update in real time by a query:

using a view:

```
create or replace view t3 as
select ssn, t1.name, t2.last, t2.ad, MAX(t1.sal, t2.sal)
  from t1, t2
 where t1.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

- or third option, you may want to create a new table based on the values of the previous one:

or create a new table, and insert the values of the two others

```
create table t3 (ssn, name, last, ad, sal);
insert into t3 select ssn, t1.name, t2.last, t2.ad, MAX(t1.sal, t2.sal)
                 from t1, t2
                where t1.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

you got the choice of the weapons! :-)

about the query, you may want to make a more complex join than the one I wrote in my examples, i.e.:

```
select * 
  from t1, t2 
 where t1.ssn = t2.ssn 
   and t1.name = t2.name 
   and (t1.last = t2.last 
     or t1.ad = t2.ad 
     or t1.sal = t2.sal);
```

as I don't really get the logic in your t3 join table's values, I don't really see what you'd want as a condition. like the column ad that has the `abc` string which comes from nowhere. But you may replace `AND` by `OR` in the previous query to change the selection behaviour, and add `IF()` expressions to select a value...

ok, then here's the reviewed query that may suit your needs (if `sal` is a number):

```
select t1.ssn, t1.name, t2.last, t2.ad, MAX(t1.sal, t2.sal)
  from t1, t2
 where t1.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

or

```
select t1.ssn as ssn, 
       t1.name as name, 
       t2.last as last , 
       t2.ad as ad, 
       if(t1.sal is null,t2.sal,t1.sal) as sal
  from t1, t2
 where t1.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

or

```
select t1.ssn as ssn, 
       t1.name as name, 
       t2.last as last , 
       t2.ad as ad, 
       case when s1.sal is null 
            then s2.sal 
            else s1.sal 
        end as sal
  from t1, t2
 where t1.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

- In oracle and postgresql (but not mysql and sqlite), you also have the [merge statement](http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html).

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience caused...I have edited the tables and now I hope u got will get my point.

Comment: Do you mean JOIN not JOINTURE?

Comment: oh, maybe, I'm sorry, I learned that in French, where we use the word "jointure" for "join" that could as well exist in English :-)

Comment: I got the answer but due to ban and poor reputation I cant post the answer.

     SQL> select t1.ssn as "SSN",case when t1.name is null then t2.name else t1.name end as "name",case when t1.last is null then t2.last else t1.last end as "last",case when
 is null then t2.ad else t1.ad end as "ad",case when t1.sal is null then t2.sal else t1.sal end as "sal" from t1,t2 where t1.ssn=t2.ssn;

Comment: well it's pretty close to what I wrote in my answer... And if you want to get a better reputation, you shall begin by accepting an answer, and read other's questions, try to answer theirs and uvote for questions and answers...

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want to "merge" the tables, but you don't give enough details to give a confident answer without some assumptions.  Three questions come to mind:

1. When there are duplicate rows, does one of the tables have precedence?
2. Do the two tables always have the same number of rows?
3. Are you really shifting the items in the second table over by one column?

Based on your data, I would say that Table1 has precedence.  I don't like to assume (2) from a sample of only three rows.  I'll assume (3) since that is how the data is structured.

So, the way to do this is through `full outer join`:

```
select  coalesce(t1.ss1, t2.ssn) as ssn, t1.NAME,
        coalesce(t1.last, t2.name) as last,
        coalesce(t1.ad, t2.last) as ad,
        coalesce(t1.sal, t2.sal) as sal
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

Comment: its not giving the proper output rather output is same as table 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    * 
 FROM t1
  UNION ALL
 SELECT
   *
 FROM t2
```

Comment: the output is same as table t2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data that's displayed in `t3`, I'm assuming the following relationships between `t1` and `t2` when mapping to `t3`:

```
t3.ssn  = (t1.ssn && t2.ssn)
t3.name = t1.name
t3.last = t2.name
t3.ad   = t2.last
t3.sal  = t1.sal, unless null; t2.sal otherwise
```

If these matches are correct, you should be able to pull the data from `t1` and `t2` and insert it into `t3` with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO t3 (ssn, name, last, ad, sal) (
    SELECT
        t1.ssn, t1.name, t2.name, t2.last, IF(t1.sal IS NOT NULL, t1.sal, t2.sal)
    FROM
        t1
        JOIN t2 ON t1.ssn = t2.ssn
);
```

Comment: furniturey: your logic is correct but sql is wrong... its giving error "ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Comment: That's because you've only just added the Oracle tag @SayantanMukherjee. This is not valid in Oracle. Please ensure that you _always_ tag your question with the RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ssn,t1.name,t2.name,t2.ad,t1.sal FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 on t1.ssn=t2.ssn
```

Try this and see

Comment: Care to elaborate?  It's more helpful to explain what you're doing and teach the OP something than it is to just hand out solutions.

Comment: Im selecting the necessary column from the two table and join with the same key value.